# find $y''=x-x^{2}$ that solves also $y''=-\lambda y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Given the orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n\}$ in $L^2$ that solves Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem

$y''=-\lambda y$ which also satisfies $y(0)=y(1)=0$ (1),

find the series expansion in this basis of the solution to:

$y''=x-x^{2}$.(2)

my idea:
I shall take the orthonormal basis that solves Sturm-Liouville in $L^2$.
This will be $\{\phi_n\}$, and I find a series that satisfies (2).

Meaning $y=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\phi_{n}a_{n}$ represents a function that satisfies (2).

first I shall use the inner product of $L^2$:
$$
b_{n}=\langle x-x^{2},\sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x)\rangle
=\int_{0}^{1}(x-x^{2})\sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x)dx\\
=-\frac{\sqrt{2}(-2+2\cos(n\pi)+n\pi \sin(n\pi))}{n^{3}\pi^{3}}$$
thus
$$\Rightarrow b_{n}=\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
n\in\mathbb{Z_{\textrm{even}}}\\
n\in\mathbb{Z_{\textrm{odd}}}
\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}
0\\
\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{n^{3}\pi^{3}}
\end{array}\end{cases}$$
now this solution also satisfies (1) as it's a linear combination of solution to (1).
Hence we've found a joint solution for both.

Am I correct?

Edit:
Hmm for a solution to be solution of 1 it must also have only be a square of integer. yet it might be still correct?
[image: The original task]

**Edit:**
$n^{2}\pi^{2}a_{n}=b_{n}\\\Rightarrow a_{n}=\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{c}
n\in\mathbb{Z_{\textrm{even}}}\\
n\in\mathbb{Z_{\textrm{od}}}
\end{array} & \begin{array}{c}
0\\
\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{n^{5}\pi^{5}}
\end{array}\end{cases}$

Comment: So $y=\frac{x-x^2}{\lambda}$?

Comment: no I believe it should be sum of $y_n=\phi_n a_n$ no?

Comment: The ODE $y''=-\lambda y$ is probably easier to solve without using Sturm-Liouville.  It has solutions:
$$y(x)=\begin{cases}A\cosh(\sqrt{-\lambda}x) + B\sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}x) & \lambda<0 \\Ax+B&\lambda=0 \\ A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) &\lambda>0\end{cases}$$

Using the given conditions, we can conclude that there are only nonzero solutions for $\lambda>0$, when $\sqrt{\lambda}=n\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: every gamma that is a squared of pi by n natural is a solution to (1). $\sin(\pi x)$ for example

Comment: You somewhat misrepresented the task. As you did in the solution, you are to solve (2) using the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $-D^2$ in (1). There is no simultaneous solution of both equations, as hinted in the first comment.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I added the original task.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In your first sentence you changed that too much. In your other question the formulation was better.

Comment: @LutzLehmann can you solve it please? I probably missunderstood it.

Comment: I switched around some parts of the text so that it is closer to the task image. Your solution so far is correct, you have found a representation of the right side. Better write that as $x-x^2=\sum b_n\phi_n$, you computed the $b_n$. Now you need to invert the differential operator in this basis.

Comment: if I have $b_n$ what is left? @LutzLehmann

Comment: You need to solve $λ_na_n=b_n$ for the $a_n$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I edited as you mentioned. can you explain the whole flow of the proof, as it turns to black magic to me. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm ... I am confused. How should you represent a non-even and non-odd function $x-x^2$ (does still have this property after double integration) by using only odd functions like the sine?

Comment: Note that the solution is a sine Fourier series of $x-x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding both sides of $y''=r(x)=x-x^2$ gives the equation
$$
-\sum\lambda_na_n\phi_n=\sum b_n\phi_n
\\
\implies a_n=-\frac{b_n}{\lambda_n}
$$
where
$$
b_n=\langle r(x),\phi_n(x)\rangle
$$
as you computed. This gives that the non-trivial coefficients are those with odd index $n$ and
$$
a_n=-\frac{4\sqrt2}{n^5\pi^5}
$$

---

Test: Direct integration and application of the boundary conditions $y(0)=y(1)=0$ gives as solution
$$
y(x)=-\frac{x}{12}(x^3-2x^2+1)
=-\frac{x(x-1)}{12}(x^2-x-1)
=-\frac{x(1-x)}{12}(1+x(1-x))
$$
Now computing the expansion coefficients gives
$$
a_n=⟨y(x),ϕ_n(x)⟩=-\frac{2\sqrt2(1-\cos(n\pi))}{n^5\pi^5}
$$
which confirms the solution.